# Nano-x cross-compile for ARM

Tags: arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile nano-x for arm architecture.

I edited in config file next lines:

> **ARCH                     = LINUX-ARM 
>
>   ARMTOOLSPREFIX           = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-**

After I run make and I have next error:

```
Compiling engine/image_jpeg.c ...
cc1: warning: include location "/usr/include/freetype2" is unsafe for cross-compilation
/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/engine/image_jpeg.c:49: fatal error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/obj/engine/image_jpeg.o] Error 1
make: *** [subdir-/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/mwin] Error 2
```

Also after each compiling I have a warnings:

```
cc1: warning: include location "/usr/include/some file" is unsafe for cross-compilation
```

I tried to compile for my architecture, everything went well. Demo is running.

There is next problem:

```
In function 'MwSelect':
/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/mwin/winmain.c:356: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/mwin/winmain.c:357: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/mwin/winmain.c:358: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
make[1]: *** [/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/obj/mwin/winmain.o] Error 1
make: *** [subdir-/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/mwin] Error 2
```

Comment: There is next problem:
`In function 'MwSelect':
/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/mwin/winmain.c:356: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/mwin/winmain.c:357: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/mwin/winmain.c:358: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
make[1]: *** [/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/obj/mwin/winmain.o] Error 1
make: *** [subdir-/home/user/oe/nanox/microwindows-0.92/src/mwin] Error 2
`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're compiling against your build system's header files rather than the target's.  This is a recipe for bizarre crashes due to version mismatches.

Compiling with  `--sysroot=<target-root>`  - where `<target-root>` is the root directory of the target filing system image, including headers and library files.

Comment: Thanks.
I must edit config file and set there INC* values. Ex.: 
INCT1LIB                 = /usr/include